# MathJax elements attribute specified on startup, but still applys to everything

Tags: mathjax

I want to only apply MathJax to text inside `<span class="math-tex"></span>`

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/startup/startup.html), I have added the following.

```js
  <script> 
    MathJax = {
        startup: {
            elements: "span.math-tex",
        },
        tex: {
            inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
            displayMath: [['$$','$$'],['\\[','\\]']],
            processEscapes: true
        }
    }
  </script> 
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.1/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

However, MathJax still typesets the entire page. I know as a last resort I could do `MathJax.typeset(document.querySelectorAll('span.math-tex'))` on window load, but I'd rather do it the way it was intended if possible. Has anyone else faced similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.  First, according to the documentation you link to, the `elements` is supposed to be an *array* of elements or element selectors, not just a single string.  So you should use

```js
            elements: ["span.math-tex"]
```

Second, there was a big in the handling of the `elements` array in version 3.0.1 (see the [issue report](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2371)) that is fixed in the current version (3.0.5), so you need to update to that version.

E.g.,

```html
<script> 
    MathJax = {
        startup: {
            elements: ["span.math-tex"]
        },
        tex: {
            inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
            displayMath: [['$$','$$'],['\\[','\\]']],
            processEscapes: true
        }
    }
  </script> 
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.5/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
  
$$\text{not processed}$$

<span class="math-tex">
$$\text{processed}$$
</span>
```