# Does Mathjax substitutes double backslash outside of math environment?

Tags: mathjax

Mathjax seems to substitute double backslash with single backslash even outside of math environment.

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Mathjax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>

    \\

</body>
</html>
```

The resulting webpage displays one backslash. Remove the Mathjax script and the webpage displays two backslash as expected.

This quirk interferes with writing TeX code verbatim on the webpage. Is there a way to stop the behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MathJax elements attribute specified on startup, but still applys to everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62109218/mathjax-elements-attribute-specified-on-startup-but-still-applys-to-everything)

Comment: @Marijn Two backslash is not a Mathjax environment afaik, so it should not be substituted. Or am I making a mistake here? I do not want to add some specifier to Mathjax other than the default ones.

Comment: MathJax by default substitutes everything in the document body, see https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/startup/startup.html: `elements: null,          // The elements to typeset (default is document body)`

Comment: You can also do it the other way around and wrap the whole page in `div class="tex2jax_ignore"` (see https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/document.html) but then you will also need to explicitly mark the parts that you _do_ want to process.

Comment: @Marijn But double backslash is not a math expression. It is also not wrapped in any of the normal math wrappers. I cannot understand why Mathjax needs to process it.

Comment: If you want to switch that off you can set `tex: {
    processEscapes: false
  }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is described in https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2532, which provides the option `processEscapes: false` as a solution. That Github issue contains the following explanation:

> This is part of the action taken when the TeX option `processEscapes` is true (the default). That option controls whether `\` can be used to escape dollar signs (e.g., `\$`) rather than using them as inline math delimiters. When this is true, `\\` is used to escape `\` as well (so that you can enter a literal `\$` as `\\\$`).

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Mathjax</title>
<script>
MathJax = {
   tex: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ],
      processEscapes: false
   }
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
\\
Inline: $\fbox{I'm in a box}$. Equation:
$$x = \frac{3}{2}$$
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this means that you cannot use a literal dollar sign in your html code anymore, however within a math expression you can still use `\$` to render a dollar sign. Also when you remove `['$','$']` from the inline math options you can use `$` and `\$` in the html without problems.